strange bound on correlation for symmetric pdf
I am puzzled by a rather simple fact:
The correlation of a symmetric multivariate pdf seems to be bound from below (increasingly strong with the number of dimensions). That seems unlikely to me.
But I can't find any mistake in my reasoning:
Let $f$ be a symmetric joint pdf for the random variates $X_1, ... X_n$ all in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\forall i,j \in {1...n}:& \\
&f(\dots x_{i-1}, x_i, x_{i+1}, \dots x_{j-1}, x_j, x_{j+1}, \dots) = \\
&f(\dots x_{i-1}, x_j, x_{i+1}, \dots x_{j-1}, x_i, x_{j+1}, \dots)
\end{align*}
$$
Since $f$ is symmetric all the marginal distributions are equal
$$
\begin{align*}
f_{X_1}(x) 
&= \int f(x, x_2, \dots) \text{d} x_{2} \dots \text{d} x_{n} =  \\
&= \int f(x_2, x, \dots) \text{d} x_{2} \dots \text{d} x_{n} = f_{X_2}(x) 
\end{align*}
$$
and thus all of the following expectation values, variances and covariances are identical.
$$
\begin{align*}
\forall i,j \in {1...n}, i\ne j:& \\
\epsilon &:= \text{Exp}\left[X_i\right] \\
\nu      &:= \text{Var}\left[X_i\right] \\
c        &:= \text{Cov}\left[X_i, X_j\right] \\
\rho     &:= \rho\left[X_i, X_j\right] = \frac{c}{\nu}\\
\end{align*}
$$
The fun begins with
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \right] 
&= \sum_i \text{Var}\left[X_i\right] + \sum_{i\ne j}\text{Cov}\left[X_i, X_j\right] = \\
&= n \nu + n(n-1)c = n\nu \left(1 + (n-1)\frac{c}{\nu}\right)= n\nu (1 + (n-1)\rho)
\end{align*}
$$
Since the variance is positive I get
$$
\begin{align*}
0<& 1 + (n-1)\rho \\
\Leftrightarrow  \rho >& -\frac{1}{(n-1)}
\end{align*}
$$
This can't be true?!
Edit
If so, wouldn't it mean that the more dimensions I have there is less and less freedom to find symmetric pdfs that are anti-correlated. What's the intuition behind this?

It is true.

Thanks for the link, I didn't see that result. I am still struggling to comprehend this. The result seems to be so general and restricting.

It is. $$\pmatrix{1&-1&-1\-1&1&-1\-1&-1&1}$$ is not a correlation matrix.

When we have a $n\times n$-correlation matrix of the form
$$
\pmatrix{1&\rho&\dots&\dots&\rho\\\rho&\ddots&&&\vdots\\\vdots&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
\vdots&&&\ddots&\rho\\\rho&\dots&\dots&\rho&1}
$$
and $n>2$ there is a restriction on how negative the constant $\rho$ can be to
guarantee that the matrix is positive semidefinite.
Another proof: Doing row operations we can calculate the determinant of the matrix as
\begin{align}
&\det\pmatrix{1&\rho&\dots&\rho\\\rho-1&1-\rho&&\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\\&&\rho-1&1-\rho}
\end{align}
and develop it by the first column. It should not be hard to see that this determinant is
$$
(1-\rho)^{n-1}\big(1+(n-1)\rho\big)\,.
$$
Since $\rho\in[-1,1]$ the determinant is therefore nonnegative if and only if
$$\tag1
\rho\ge-\frac1{n-1}\,.
$$
Another remark which simplifies the linked answer a bit:
Using the same row operations it is easy to see that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is
$$
p(\lambda)=(1-\lambda-\rho)^{n-1}\Big(1-\lambda+(n-1)\rho\Big)
$$
so that the eigenvalues are
$$
\lambda_1=1-\rho\,,\quad \lambda_2=1+(n-1)\rho 
$$
with multiplicities $n-1$ and one, respectively. Since the eigenvalue $1-\rho$ is nonnegative the matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if the inequality (1) holds.
